# ImageButton Position programmatically

Tags: android, xml, layout, imagebutton

I'm using XML for the layout but I need to programmatically position the ImageButton. Can anyone gives me an idea how to do it?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainScreenLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/mainScreenImage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:src="@drawable/screenimage"/>

<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/titleview"
android:background="#00000000"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/buttonstart"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: @Nizam I tried what 1) Rudra said below by changing AbsoluteLayout to FrameLayout but couldnt compile, 2) tried setBoundsInScreen(Rect) but I did't know how to use it properly so couldnt compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, wrap the ImageButton with a FrameLayout as

```
....
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/titleview"
android:background="#00000000"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/buttonstart"/>

</FrameLayout>
....
```

This is not a must, to be a FrameLayout. **Just wrap the image with some layout**. But for other layouts, positioning with X and Y will vary.

Now, I can change the position of ImageButton as,

```
FrameLayout mFrame=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
mFrame.setPadding(fromLeftX, fromTopY, fromRight, fromBottom);
```

Comment: You are welcome. As a new user, you may not be aware that you can accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark above. Happy new year

Answer (score 0):

i think LayoutParams will work fine
try this code

```
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
        (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
    absParams.x = myNewX;
    absParams.y = myNewY;
    button.setLayoutParams(absParams);
```

and if you want to set image on it use setBackgroundResources property

```
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_image);
```

Comment: you know how to do it in a FrameLayout?

Comment: Absolute layout params is deprecated